# Не работает кнопка обновления корзины в Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Вставил в свою верстку корзины кнопку обновления этой корзины при изменении количества товаров например. Ничего не трогал, просто заменил на свои классы. При нажатии на кнопку — страница обновляется, но ничего не меняется. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откройте консоль в испекторе и посмотрите, что возвращается в ajax вызове. Там будут ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вообще отказался от подобных кнопок. Это лишние клики для пользователей. Можете сделать автоматическую смену стоимости, в зависимости от количества товаров в корзине.

```
/* Автоматическое обновление корзины в зависимости от изменения количества товара */
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_qty_script' );

function cart_update_qty_script() {
    if (is_cart()) :
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change', '.qty', function(){
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").removeAttr('disabled');
            jQuery("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
        });
    </script>
    <?php

endif;
}
```

Нужно добавить данный код в файл functions.php вашей дочерней темы.